# How to find the intersection points on the scatter plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, regression

I draw a graph by means of scatter plot and now it's necessary to find the intersection points on it. How to calculate that?

I expected the result like on the attached image.
[image]

I have already tried to go through the skelet (array) coordinates and calculate the difference between two neighbouring coordinates on the one of the axis as code shows:

```
def get_all_sceleton_coords(skel):
    skel_coords = []    # arr with all coordinates on the plot
    for x in range(skel.shape[0]):
        for y in range(skel.shape[1]):
            if skel[x, y] > 0:
                skel_coords.append([x, y])
    return skel_coords

skel_coords = get_all_sceleton_coords(skel)
branches = []
for n, coord in enumerate(skel_coords):
    # We go through the array coordinates and search for the last pixel number which difference with the neighbouring pixel less than 1
    if skel_coords[n][0]-skel_coords[n-1][0] < 1:
        branches.append(skel_coords[n])
```

But in this case the results are very inaccurate.
Is there any in-box methods how to find intersections on the several arrays or how to apply the polynomial regression to that graph with branches?
Thanks for answers!

Comment: What is `skel`?

Comment: @Goyo skel = skeleton, that is the array of points of the image. Sorry I didn't point it out in the post. upd: improved, thanks!

Comment: I have a Python "scatterplot data extractor" that gave the X-Y values from the visual center of the two red dots as [2.5009e+02, 2.1096e+02] and [2.3872e+02, 2.5831e+02]. Using this would entail saving each scatterplot image, running the data extractor to load the image file, and then and manually clicking on the visible intersection points as I did with the posted image. If your process must be automated this would not be useful.

Comment: @JamesPhillips Thank you! Unfortunately I need to make the same thing automatically

Comment: If you have sparse lines such as this one, I think the best approach should be at any given point find the number of neighboring points within a circle (say r=10). If you find more than two points, then slowly narrow down the circle and pin point the intersection point